# Vertical Pod-Autoscaler does not recreate

Tags: kubernetes

I want that Kubernetes recreate my pod with higher resources after a cpu stresstest but it does not recreate the pods, the recomandation has changed Can I somewhere control how often my VerticalPodAutoscaler checks the CPU/RAM Metrics? And is Recreate or Auto the better mode for this scenario?

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-vpa
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
    kind:       Deployment
    name:       my-auto-deployment
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Recreate"
```

Update:

[image]

so the main problem is that the recommendations changed but it does not recreate the pod.

[image]

The pod resources did not change/recreate

Answer (score 1):

By default, VPA checks the metrics values at every 10s intervals. VPA requires the pods to be restarted to change allocated resources.

Comment: can i change this interval? yes but it did not restart the pods thats the strange part

Comment: I added a picture, this shows how the recommendations changed but the pod stays at 25m

Comment: The updater doesn't perform the actual resources update. The pod needs to be evicted based on pod disruption policy.

Comment: do you think a k8s object PodDisruptionBudget with minAvailable: 0 would work?